# MVC Updating Items in a Table without page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here's what I am looking for :

I have table which get's populated by model in my view as such :

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ReviewList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.MatchId</td>
            <td>
                <ul class="list-unstyled addressList">
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine1</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine2</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine3</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine4</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine5</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine6</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine7</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine8</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine9</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.InputAddressLine10</span></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="list-unstyled addressList">
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine1</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine2</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine3</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine4</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine5</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine6</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine7</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine8</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine9</span></li>
                    <li><span>@item.MatchAddressLine10</span></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>@item.GeoIDMatched</td>
            <td>@item.RejectionReason</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

In this I basically list all my rejected items i.e. StatusID = 3 and next to each row in the table above I want to add a link/button when clicked on would then update this row's StatusID = 4 and then remove from this list and table since it's no longer StatusID = 3.

So I am looking whats the best way to add a button to each row in this table, and manage the data in the table to be updated ?

Comment: enter ajax. asynchronously call the controller to update both tables. Maybe use json.

Comment: Try something like this: http://www.jtable.org/, or any similar JQuery plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty method would be to add another column at the end of the table, that calls an update method in your controller, and passes the MatchID of each item as a parameter (assuming that ID is unique).

```
<td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new { id=@item.MatchID })
</td>
```

Inside the method, look up the item in your datasource using the MatchID, and then set the StatusID to 4.

You can then use AJAX to refresh the page content without actually refreshing the page.

Comment: The Update function, would that just be an a normal action result ?

Comment: @StevieB - Yes it would.